# Polynomial Regression Using statsmodels.formula.api

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

Please forgive my ignorance.  All I'm trying to do is add a squared term to my regression without going through the trouble of defining a new column in my dataframe.  I'm using statsmodels.formula.api (as stats) because the format is similar to R, which I am more familiar with.

```
hours_model = stats.ols(formula='act_hours ~ h_hours + C(month) + trend', data = df).fit()
```

The above works as expected.

```
hours_model = stats.ols(formula='act_hours ~ h_hours + h_hours**2 + C(month) + trend', data = df).fit()
```

This omits h_hours**2 and returns the same output as the line above.

I've also tried: h_hours^2, math.pow(h_hours,2), and poly(h_hours,2) 
All throw errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What dtype are the `h_hours` values? If it's treated as categorical, then you need to convert to float or some other type that is treated by patsy as numeric.

Comment: please take a look at sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures it will help.

Comment: @Josef, thank you for your response.  The dtype for df['h_hours'] is float64.

Comment: @GIRISHkuniyal, thanks.  I looked into it, but I don't think it fits for what I'm trying to do.  I'm just looking for a squared term without any interaction.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try using `I()` like in R:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'act_hours':np.random.uniform(1,4,100),'h_hours':np.random.uniform(1,4,100),
                  'month':np.random.randint(0,3,100),'trend':np.random.uniform(0,2,100)})

model = 'act_hours ~ h_hours + I(h_hours**2)'
hours_model = smf.ols(formula = model, data = df)

hours_model.exog[:5,]

array([[ 1.        ,  3.03344961,  9.20181654],
       [ 1.        ,  1.81002392,  3.27618659],
       [ 1.        ,  3.20558207, 10.27575638],
       [ 1.        ,  3.88656564, 15.10539244],
       [ 1.        ,  1.74625943,  3.049422  ]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently, although the statsmodels formula API (in fact Patsy library) doesn't support `poly(variable, degree)` function as in R, NumPy's `vander(variable, degree+1)` can do the job. However, pay **attention** that `np.vander()` produces the Vandermonde matrix which means you get intercept column too! Let's see this function in an example:

```
>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5])
>> np.vander(x, 4, increasing=True)

array([[  1,   1,   1,   1],
       [  1,   2,   4,   8],
       [  1,   3,   9,  27],
       [  1,   5,  25, 125]])
```

So, you need to remove Patsy's internal intercept by adding `-1` to your formula:

```
hours_model = stats.ols(formula='act_hours ~ np.vander(h_hours, 3, increasing=True) - 1', data = df).fit()
```

Note that you need to pass `your_desired_degree + 1` because the first column is x^0=1.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the answer by Mohammad-Reza Malekpour, but removes the intercept column from the Vandermonde matrix.

```py
import numpy as np


def poly(x, degree):
    return np.vander(x, degree + 1, increasing=True)[:, 1:]
```

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

n = 30
np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=n)
y = 1 + 2 * x + 3 * x**2 + 4 * x**3 + np.random.normal(0, 0.001, size=n)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y})

results = smf.ols(formula="y ~ poly(x, 3)", data=df).fit()
print(results.summary().tables[1])
```

```
=================================================================================
                    coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept         1.0009      0.001   1599.564      0.000       1.000       1.002
poly(x, 3)[0]     1.9935      0.006    361.673      0.000       1.982       2.005
poly(x, 3)[1]     3.0124      0.013    232.711      0.000       2.986       3.039
poly(x, 3)[2]     3.9919      0.009    463.711      0.000       3.974       4.010
=================================================================================
```

Compared with:

```py
results = smf.ols(formula="y ~ x + I(x**2) + I(x**3)", data=df).fit()
print(results.summary().tables[1])
```

```
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      1.0009      0.001   1599.564      0.000       1.000       1.002
x              1.9935      0.006    361.673      0.000       1.982       2.005
I(x ** 2)      3.0124      0.013    232.711      0.000       2.986       3.039
I(x ** 3)      3.9919      0.009    463.711      0.000       3.974       4.010
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Your poly function is very helpful to write formula for variables with multiple terms without having to write each term one by one. Thank you :-)